# What are the best practices for connecting web applications to EOS?

Tags: best-practices

I couldn't find any published work on best practices for connecting web applications to EOS. Specifically, I am looking for security and performance best practices that web developers should implement in connecting web users to the EOS blockchain.

For example, there is eosjs, scatter-js Javascript "middleware" that ties web applications to EOS. Similarly, there is cleos on the backend for implementing batch (cron) jobs with hot wallets. But I cannot seem to find a documented best practice guide to help out non-blockchain developers connecting with EOS.

Answer (score 1):

For connecting scatter with dapp follow this link https://get-scatter.com/docs/examples-interaction-flow

For eosjs related documentation i think eosjs's github rapo is perfect for integrating with dapp follow https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/tree/v16.0.9 
 **OR**  https://eosio.github.io/eosjs/